# How to parse Telnyx JSON in Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to parse the JSON received from Telnyx (through a webhook) in a Google spreadsheet, using in cell formulas.
The ideal outcome is to having data from each line in a separate column (including lines with no data), with the correct heading.
JS would also be an option.

I've tried using FILTER and REGEXMATCH with some results, but I couldn't manage to get a decent output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The data received from Telnyx looks like this:

```
"{
 ""data"": {
 ""event_type"": ""message.received"",
 ""id"": ""0d9c22"",
 ""occurred_at"": ""2022-07-23T04:52:08.642+00:00"",
 ""payload"": {
 ""cc"": [],
 ""completed_at"": null,
 ""cost"": null,
 ""direction"": ""inbound"",
 ""encoding"": ""GSM-7"",
 ""errors"": [],
 ""from"": {
 ""carrier"": """",
 ""line_type"": """",
 ""phone_number"": ""+447""
 },
 ""id"": ""eb17"",
 ""media"": [],
 ""messaging_profile_id"": ""4001"",
 ""organization_id"": ""8ab"",
 ""parts"": 2,
 ""received_at"": ""2022-07-20T04:52:08.464+00:00"",
 ""record_type"": ""message"",
 ""sent_at"": null,
 ""subject"": """",
 ""tags"": [],
 ""text"": ""SMS goes here.\nThanks"",
 ""to"": [
 {
 ""carrier"": ""Telnyx"",
 ""line_type"": ""Wireless"",
 ""phone_number"": ""+447"",
 ""status"": ""webhook_delivered""
 }
 ],
 ""type"": ""SMS"",
 ""valid_until"": null,
 ""webhook_failover_url"": null,
 ""webhook_url"": ""https://script.google.com/XXXXX""
 },
 ""record_type"": ""event""
 },
 ""meta"": {
 ""attempt"": 1,
 ""delivered_to"": ""https://script.google.com/""
 }
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursive function (A1 contains the data)

```
=functionTelnyx(A1)
```

put in your script editor

```
function functionTelnyx(json) {
  const telnyx = JSON.parse(json.slice(1,-1).replace(/""/g,'"').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm, ""))
  let result = [];
  recursion(telnyx)
  function recursion(obj, path) {
    if (path == undefined) { path = 'telnyx' }
    const regex = new RegExp('[^0-9]+');
    for (let p in obj) {
      let newPath = (regex.test(p)) ? path + '.' + p : path + '[' + p + ']';
      if (obj[p] != null) {
        if (typeof obj[p] != 'object' && typeof obj[p] != 'function') {
          result.push([ p, obj[p]]);
        }
        if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
          recursion(obj[p], newPath);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

[image]

### edit:

for multiple json, and horizontal layout

- for headers, put in B1 `=telnyx_headers(A2)`
- for contents, put in B2 and drag below `=telnyx_contents(A2)`, then `=telnyx_contents(A3)` and so forth

with

```
function telnyx_headers(json) {
  const telnyx = JSON.parse(json.slice(1, -1).replace(/""/g, '"').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm, ""))
  let result = [];
  recursion(telnyx)
  function recursion(obj, path) {
    if (path == undefined) { path = 'telnyx' }
    const regex = new RegExp('[^0-9]+');
    for (let p in obj) {
      let newPath = (regex.test(p)) ? path + '.' + p : path + '[' + p + ']';
      if (obj[p] != null) {
        if (typeof obj[p] != 'object' && typeof obj[p] != 'function') {
          result.push(p);
        }
        if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
          recursion(obj[p], newPath);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return [result]
}
function telnyx_contents(json) {
  const telnyx = JSON.parse(json.slice(1, -1).replace(/""/g, '"').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm, ""))
  let result = [];
  recursion(telnyx)
  function recursion(obj, path) {
    if (path == undefined) { path = 'telnyx' }
    const regex = new RegExp('[^0-9]+');
    for (let p in obj) {
      let newPath = (regex.test(p)) ? path + '.' + p : path + '[' + p + ']';
      if (obj[p] != null) {
        if (typeof obj[p] != 'object' && typeof obj[p] != 'function') {
          result.push(obj[p]);
        }
        if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
          recursion(obj[p], newPath);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return [result]
}
```

### optional: array-enabled version

To process a larger number of JSON strings in the column `A2:A`, use this formula:

`=telnyx(A2:A)`

The `telnyx()` function uses `telnyx_headers()` and `telnyx_contents()` while observing [custom function best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization).

```js
/**
* Converts one or more JSON strings to a horizontal table.
* Row 1 will show field names and subsequent rows the
* data in each field.
*
* @param {A2:A} json The JSON strings to convert to a table.
* @customfunction
*/
function telnyx(json) {
  'use strict';
  if (!Array.isArray(json)) {
    json = [json];
  }
  json = json.flat();
  let result = telnyx_headers(json[0]);
  json.forEach(j => result = result.concat(j ? telnyx_contents(j) : [null]));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Mike Steelson, this brings a big improvement to my spreadsheet.
Would it be possible to display the data horizontally rather than vertically?
Something like this:
Row 1: Header row.
Row 2: A2 = JSON; B2, C2 = parsed data from A2.
Row 3: A3 = JSON; B3, C3 = parsed data from A3.

Comment: For a quick fix, use `=transpose(functionTelnyx(A2))`, `=transpose(functionTelnyx(A4))` and so on. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).

Comment: Good answer from doubleunary!  However I will update to give you another solution assuming that all json have strictly the same structure!

Comment: Looks good. Added an array-enabled helper function.